# Move Sprite in constant speed on squircle

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating a game and i need to move a sprite on `squircle` path (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).

i created the path using the  equation :

```
    angle -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*speed ;
    float x = (float) (R*Math.pow(Math.abs(MathUtils.cos(angle)),1/10f)*sgn(MathUtils.cos(angle)))+a;
    float y = (float) (R*Math.pow(Math.abs(MathUtils.sin(angle)),1/10f)*sgn(MathUtils.sin(angle)))+b;
    sprite.setPosition(x,y);
```

the result is :
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgrxB.gif)

My question is how to make the sprite move in a constant speed

Edit :
i used the formula found on Wikipedia : [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdvoH.png)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail your formula?

Comment: i added the formula that i used

Comment: To draw circle formula is simple:
`x = R * cos(alpha);   y = R * sin(alpha)`

Comment: i'm not trying to draw a circle .. it's called Squircle . it's a square with round corners ..

Comment: Ohh, ok. I missed it.
The problem is that time (distance) is not linear to the angle in the equation you have found.

Comment: i think so.. any ideas how to solve it

Comment: You might want to post this in Mathematics. http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i deleted my post because it was useless, look at this picture http://prntscr.com/bb1y0m this is the path that your formula prints and your circle moves on it. if you increase your exponential parameter (1/10) dots will be look more closer to each other if you make it 1, the shape will be a perfect circle, so this is the nature of this formula, i can suggest you to create and array and put all x,y values in there and fill the blanks , that single dots on the border should be the result of angle 0, 90 ,180, 270, i didnt calculate it but it could start with 45, 135 , and so on ...